# TSQL: split value in time

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a basic table dbo.Basic

```
start_date                end_date                  task     value
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
2016-01-12 13:02:00.000   2016-01-12 17:18:00.000   400001   12675.59370000
2016-01-13 03:09:00.000   2016-01-13 07:48:00.000   400002   13689.93600000
2016-01-13 07:48:00.000   2016-01-13 12:13:00.000   400003   12001.64456400
2016-01-13 12:13:00.000   2016-01-13 20:45:00.000   400004   23189.46598800
```

and I'd like to distribute the value in time (**with a 1-minute granularity**) grouped in max. 1-hour-interval

```
start_date                end_date                  task     value
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
2016-01-12 13:02:00.000   2016-01-12 14:00:00.000   400001   <calculated part of value for 400001>
2016-01-12 14:00:00.000   2016-01-12 15:00:00.000   400001   <calculated part of value for 400001>
2016-01-12 15:00:00.000   2016-01-12 16:00:00.000   400001   ...
2016-01-12 16:00:00.000   2016-01-12 17:00:00.000   400001   ...
2016-01-12 17:00:00.000   2016-01-12 17:18:00.000   400001   ...
2016-01-13 03:09:00.000   2016-01-13 04:00:00.000   400002   <calculated part of value for 400002>
2016-01-13 04:00:00.000   2016-01-13 05:00:00.000   400002  ...
...
etc.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your could use a [recursive CTE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx) like this

```
DECLARE @SampleData AS TABLE
(
   start_date datetime,
   end_date datetime,
   task int
)

INSERT INTO @SampleData
VALUES
('2016-01-12 13:02:00.000','2016-01-12 17:18:00.000', 400001)  
,('2016-01-13 03:09:00.000','2016-01-13 07:48:00.000', 400002)  
,('2016-01-13 07:48:00.000','2016-01-13 12:13:00.000', 400003)  
,('2016-01-13 12:13:00.000','2016-01-13 20:45:00.000', 400004)

;WITH temp AS 
(
   SELECT sd.start_date, dateadd(hour, datediff(hour,0,sd.start_date) + 1,0) AS end_date, sd.end_date as actual_enddate, sd.task
   FROM @SampleData sd
   UNION ALL
   SELECT  t.end_date, 
         CASE 
            WHEN dateadd(hour, 1,t.end_date) < t.actual_enddate THEN dateadd(hour, 1,t.end_date) 
            ELSE t.actual_enddate 
         END AS end_date,
         t.actual_enddate, 
         t.task
   FROM temp t
   WHERE t.end_date != t.actual_enddate
)
SELECT t.start_date,t.end_date,t.task
FROM temp t
ORDER BY t.task 
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Demo link: http://rextester.com/GQN93710

Comment: thanks; complete final select

    SELECT t.start_date
 ,t.end_date
 ,datediff(MINUTE, t.start_date, t.end_date) AS duration_min
 ,part.value_s
 ,cast((datediff(MINUTE, t.start_date, t.end_date)) / cast((part.value_s) AS DECIMAL(15, 8)) AS DECIMAL(15, 8)) * cast(t.value AS DECIMAL(15, 8)) AS FINAL_VALUE
 ,t.task
 ,t.value
    FROM TEMP t
    LEFT JOIN (
 SELECT tt.task
  ,sum(datediff(MINUTE, tt.start_date, tt.end_date)) AS value_s
 FROM TEMP tt
 GROUP BY tt.task
 ) part ON t.task = part.task
    ORDER BY t.task
    OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)

Comment: I think the most important thing is 'an approach' to resolve your problem, not exactly answer. Anyway, thanks for sharing ...